# struggling with os.rename() function

Tags: python

I'm attempting to remove the underscores for every file in the downloads folder in python 3 yet my program ends up with an error

Here is my code so far:

```
import shutil, os, re
for folder, downloads, songs in os.walk("C:/Users/TheTrojanHorse/Downloads"):
    print("the current folder is",folder)
    for song in songs:
        temp = song
        temp = (re.sub('[_]', ' ',temp))
        os.rename(song,temp)
```

This is the error:

```
os.rename(song,temp)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Your title mentions `os.rename`, but your code only has `os.remove`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Kevin Ah sorry that was my old code, will update now

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to use regex to replace a string with another string. `temp.replace("_", " ")` works just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the full path to `song` (and likely `temp`) as otherwise the operating system will be looking for the file in the current directory and not in `C:/Users/TheTrojanHorse/Downloads`:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(folder, song), os.path.join(folder, temp))
```

Comment: i plugged this in but now this happened: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists. I dont understand how the os.rename() would cause this error to happen @NPE

Comment: @TrojanHorse: The exception is exactly what it says on the tin. This behaviour is even spelled out in the documentation ("On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised..." - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: Please follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296315/renaming-images-in-folder/51296626#51296626.  full file path is only way to rename file.